# PhpStorm moving static method not working

Tags: php, static, phpstorm

When I want to move a static method from one class to another, every call to `SiteController::myMethod();` should become `MyNewClass::myMethod();`.

But PhpStorm behaves strange. In some parts of my project it correctly substitutes `SiteController::myMethod();` with `MyNewClass::myMethod();`, but in others parts of my project "`SiteController`" is substituted with "`SomeAnotherClass`".

Why does this error occur?

Comment: With this kind of issues you better have some reproducible case and submit it to their **[Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI)** as it looks like a bug & requires some additional info (e.g. your `idea.log`, some info about project structure and project settings) without which it cannot be debugged. I also suggest to try 1) `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE; 2) Disable all 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins